Proving a question about Mathematical Proof by Induction
The question has been taken from the 1998 National Mathematical Contest. The problem is from the Canada team.
Let $n$ be a natural number such that $n\ge2$. Show that

$$ ({\frac {1}{n+1}})× (1+{\frac {1}{3}}+{\frac {1}{5} + ... + {\frac {1}{2n-1}}}) > ({\frac {1}{n}})× (1+{\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {1}{4} + ... + {\frac {1}{2n}}}) $$

Solution 
We prove that

$$ n× (1+{\frac {1}{3}}+{\frac {1}{5} + ... + {\frac {1}{2n-1}}}) > (n+1)× (1+{\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {1}{4} + ... + {\frac {1}{2n}}}) $$

by induction.
For n=2, 8/3 > 9/4. Assume the claim is true for n=k>=2 i.e. we have

(1) $$  k× (1+{\frac {1}{3}}+{\frac {1}{5} + ... + {\frac {1}{2k-1}}}) > (k+1)×(1+{\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {1}{4} + ... + {\frac {1}{2k}}}) $$

Now let n = k+1. Note that

(2) $$ (1+{\frac {1}{3}}+{\frac {1}{5} + ... + {\frac {1}{2k-1}}}) + {\frac {k+1}{2k+1}} = ({\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {1}{3}} +{\frac {1}{4}+ ... + {\frac {1}{2k-1}}}) + {\frac {1}{2}} + {\frac {k+1}{2k+1}} $$
(3) $$ > ({\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {1}{4}} +{\frac {1}{6}+ ... + {\frac {1}{2k}}}) + {\frac {1}{2}} + {\frac {k+1}{2k+1}}  $$
(4) $$ > ({\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {1}{4}} +{\frac {1}{6}+ ... + {\frac {1}{2k}}}) + {\frac {k+1}{2k+2}} + {\frac {1}{2k+1}}  $$
(5) $$ > ({\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {1}{4}} +{\frac {1}{6}+ ... + {\frac {1}{2k}}}) + {\frac {k+2}{2k+2}}   $$

Induction is complete as

(6) $$  (k+1) \bigg({1+{\frac {1}{3}}+ ... + {\frac {1}{2k-1}}}\bigg) + {\frac {1}{2k+1}}) = k * ({1+{\frac {1}{3}}+ ... + {\frac {1}{2k-1}}}) + ({1+{\frac {1}{3}}+ ... + {\frac {1}{2k-1}}}) + {\frac {k+1}{2k+1}}  $$


(7) $$ > k (1+{\frac {1}{3}}+ ... + {\frac {1}{2k-1}}) + ( {\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {1}{4}}+ ... + {\frac {1}{2k}}) + ({\frac {k+2}{2k+2}}  )   $$


(8) $$ > (k+2) ({\frac {1}{2}}+ {\frac {1}{4}}+... + {\frac {1}{2k+2}}) $$

The problem is that how did we obtain the equation 1? If we write k+1 instead of n, as the proof by induction points out in equation 1, we should have obtained the following equation:

(9) $$ (k+1) *({\frac {1}{2}}+ {\frac {1}{4}}+... + {\frac {1}{2k+1}}) > (k+2) * (1+{\frac {1}{2}}+ {\frac {1}{4}}+... + {\frac {1}{2k+4}})$$

How did we obtain equation 2? In addition, how did we obtain equation 3? Thanks in advance.

What happens if you substitute $k-1$ for $n$?

I write k-1 for n and still I cannot understand the issue.


Multiply
$$ ({\frac {1}{n+1}})* (1+{\frac {1}{3}}+{\frac {1}{5} + ... + {\frac {1}{2n-1}}}) > ({\frac {1}{n}})* (1+{\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {1}{4} + ... + {\frac {1}{2n}}}) $$
by $n(n+1)$ to get
$$ n* (1+{\frac {1}{3}}+{\frac {1}{5} + ... + {\frac {1}{2n-1}}}) > (n+1)* (1+{\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {1}{4} + ... + {\frac {1}{2n}}}) $$

Let $n = k$ to get $(1)$.

Write $1$ as $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$ to get $(2)$

$$  k* (1+{\frac {1}{3}}+{\frac {1}{5} + ... + {\frac {1}{2k-1}}}) > (k+1)* (1+{\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {1}{4} + ... + {\frac {1}{2k}}}) $$
$$\implies 1+{\frac {1}{3}}+{\frac {1}{5} + ... + {\frac {1}{2k-1}}} > \frac{k+1}{k} * (1+{\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {1}{4} + ... + {\frac {1}{2k}}}) > (1+{\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {1}{4} + ... + {\frac {1}{2k}}})$$, so we get


$$1+{\frac {1}{3}}+{\frac {1}{5} + ... + {\frac {1}{2k-1}}} > 1+{\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {1}{4} + ... + {\frac {1}{2k}}}$$, which gives $(2)>(3)$.
